# Cannot see the image of my HTML file

Tags: html

Whats going wrong with my explorer or mozilla. I used the

```
         <img src="path"/>
```

but the pic cannot be seen, when i open my html file. It just opens an empty box at that place.How do i make it through? I cannot display my pictures in my html file.Could you tell me which version of explorer supports it?

Comment: It's not a matter of support, but most likely a matter of your `path` being wrong.

Comment: maybe you need to set "width" and "height"?

Comment: @alexblum I have not yet seen a browser that would display an empty box if the `<img>` tag doesn't have `width` and `height` set.

Comment: @Juhana you are right, if this is a single tag in a document the dimensions do not metter, but if it in a complex html (i.e. some div block) may be `width` and `height` are important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your file is really named how you think it is. If you have "Hide known extensions" enabled, disable it and check again. Also, check if the extension in the path is the same case as the files. I once had a problem where images would not display in IE because of the image extensions being in upper case.

Answer (score 0):

where is your HTML file and where is your image file ?
lets suppose your HTML file is anywhere and your image is in the same directory then you can give it path src="image.extension".

better you should check it in the same directory. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your path is correct.

If the image is in the same folder as your html file, then it should just be

`<img src="image_name.jpg" />`

If you reference your images from another folder, you will need to place the proper path in there.  Depending on the file structure, it could be something like

`<img src="/images/image_name.jpg" />`

`<img src="../images/image_name.jpg" />`

`<img src="../../images/image_name.jpg" />`

Also check that you have

1. spelled the file and folder names correctly
2. used the right upper- and lowercase letters (this can be problem for file name extensions, like .jpg vs .JPG)
3. actually saved the file in the place it is supposed to be